# ClassNotFoundException ( org.apache.openjpa.slice.ProductDerivation.)

Tags: java, eclipse, apache

I m new to java ejb and I am trying to develop an app with eclipse juno, java ejb and apache tomee. I have this error while deployment:

> org.apache.openjpa.slice.ProductDerivation:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.openjpa.slice.ProductDerivation.

Can someone please tell me what is this and how to solve it ?

Comment: Place the jar containing org.apache.openjpa.slice.ProductDerivation class in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing out `openjpa-slice-2.2.1-sources.jar` from your `classpath`. You can download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadopenjpaslice221sourcesjar.htm).

Comment: Since I m begginer, I don't know how to place this jar to my classpath. I got source file (not .jar file which i would just put in my library folder and add to build path). Thanks a lot for response :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the jar into the lib/ folder of TomEE.

Comment: When I download openjpa-slice-2.2.1-sources.jar.zip it extract like a source folder. I don't know where and how to put it. Can you please tell me what to do with it. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You will not download sources. You will download compiled JAR file. Please use the related version of compile JAR file from the above link. For example, openjp-slice1.2.2.jar. After that out this JAR file to your server conf directory. Go to root of the server, there must be conf folder. Copy the JAR file into it and restart the server.